# How do I pass a subset of data to a view that has its own view model?

Tags: swiftui

Given the following...

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var value: Bool
    
    init(value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func update() {
        value = !value
    }
}

struct A: View {
    
    @ObservedObject let viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(value: Bool) {
        viewModel = ViewModel(value: value)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(String(viewModel.value))")
            .onTapGesture {
                viewModel.update()
            }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @State var val = [true, false, true]

    var body: some View {
        A(value: val[0])
    }
}
```

How do I get `viewModel` to update `B`'s `val`? It looks like I should be able to use `@Binding` inside of `A` but I can't use `@Binding` inside `ViewModel`, which is where I want the modification code to run. Then, I don't think I'd need `@ObservedObject` because the renders would flow from `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need `Binding`, or an equivalent that does the same thing, in `ViewModel`. Why do you say you can't use it?

```swift
struct A: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: Model

  init(value: Binding<Bool>) {
    model = .init(value: value)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(String(model.value))
      .onTapGesture(perform: model.update)
  }
}

extension A {
  final class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Binding private(set) var value: Bool

    init(value: Binding<Bool>) {
      _value = value
    }

    func update() {
      value.toggle()
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct B: View {
  @State var val = [true, false, true]

  var body: some View {
    A(value: $val[0])
  }
}
```

Comment: I get "Unknown attribute 'Binding'" when using @Binding inside of a view model class. But not when the class is defined in an extension as you've done.

Comment: Oh dear. I forgot import SwiftUI. So I didn't need to ask this question at all. One has to watch one's assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the value owned by a parent, you need to pass a `Binding` from the parent to the child. The child changes the `Binding`, which updates the value for the parent.

Then you'd need to update that `Binding` when the child's own view model updates. You can do this by subscribing to a `@Published` property:

```
struct A: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    @Binding var value: Bool // add a binding
    
    init(value: Binding<Bool>) {
        _value = value
        viewModel = ViewModel(value: _value.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("\(String(viewModel.value))") {
            viewModel.update()
        }
        // subscribe to changes in view model
        .onReceive(viewModel.$value, perform: {
            value = $0 // update the binding
        })
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to actually make the view model's property `@Published`:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {    
   @Published var value: Bool
   // ...
}
```